# Is it possible to trigger cloud functions in Firebase based on the user's time zone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In my Android app, I have a Firebase Cloud Function that gets triggered every day at 12:00 AM.

This is the code:

```
exports.dailyReset = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *').onRun((context) => {
    return null;
});
```

Is it possible to trigger the function based on the user's time zone? By default, it's gets triggered based on the America/Los Angeles time. This would also mean that the cloud function will get triggered at various times since multiple users using the app can be in different time zones.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I was already aware of being able to change timezones, but my question of being able to trigger cloud functions based on the user's timezone hasn't been solved. I understand it's not possible to dynamically trigger cloud functions for each user, but there has to be someway to solve it.

Comment: "Is it possible to trigger the function based on the user's time zone?" I answered that one specific question you asked. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation on [writing a scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#write_a_scheduled_function) shows, you can specify the timezone with:

> Both Unix Crontab and AppEngine syntax are supported by Google Cloud Scheduler. For example, to use Crontab to select a specific timezone in which to run a scheduled function, do something like this:
>
> ```
> exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
>  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
>  .onRun((context) => {
>  console.log('This will be run every day at 11:05 AM Eastern!');
>  return null;
> });
> ```
>
> The value for `timeZone` must be a time zone name from the [tz database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). See the [Cloud Scheduler reference](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.scheduler.v1#job) for more information on supported properties.

There is no way here to schedule on the time of a specific user of your app, as the Cloud Functions have no way of knowing each user's timezone at deploy time (which is when the schedule is set).